# ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined while using ffmpeg.wasm

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, client-side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TikTok Live Downloader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TikTok Live Downloader</h1>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input id="txt" type="text" name="username" id="username" required>
      <button type="submit">Download</button>
  </body>
<script src="ffmpeg.js"></script>
<script>
const downloadButton = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
downloadButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
const ffmpeg = FFmpeg.createFFmpeg({
     corePath: new URL('ffmpeg-core.js', document.location).href,
     workerPath: new URL('ffmpeg-core.worker.js', document.location).href,
     wasmPath: new URL('ffmpeg-core.wasm', document.location).href,
     log: true
   });
   await ffmpeg.load();
const liveUrl=document.getElementById("txt").value;
ffmpeg.run('-i', '${liveUrl}', 'c','copy','test.mp4');
const dwnLink = document.createElement('a');
dwnLink.download = `output${'test.mp4'}`;
dwnLink.href= encodedData;
dwnLink.click();
});
</script>
</html>
```

With the above code, I was trying to make a tiktok video downloader but I keep getting the SharedArrayBuffer error. I'm running this with node.js.

```
// middleware to enable SharedBuffer to be used
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
  res.header("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
  next();
});
```

I tried adding the above two lines in my app.js but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your browser doesn't support ffmpeg.wasm. Here is the list of browsers supported https://caniuse.com/sharedarraybuffer